# async функция возвращает undefined

Tags: node.js, async-await

Использую superagent для запроса из node.js.
Почему эта штука ничего не возвращает?

```
console.log(GetCover())

const GetCover = async function() {
    await request
    .get('http://coverartarchive.org/release/5b629d8b-4830-4e02-86e8-6765b1cbbf35')
    .type('application/json');
};
```

Вот что говорит консоль:

> Promise { pending }

Comment: Все правильно. Асинхронные функции всегда возвращают Promise

Comment: как из этого можно получить информацию?

Comment: Когда ничего не помогает - откройте уже, наконец, [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). [И вот еще](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вернуть что-то из функции (асинхронной или обычной) нужно использовать конструкцию `return`:

```
const GetCover = async function() {
    return await request
        .get('http://coverartarchive.org/release/5b629d8b-4830-4e02-86e8-6765b1cbbf35')
        .type('application/json');
};
```

Функция выше возвращает *Общание* (*Promise*), которое будет выполнено **когда** будут получены данные или отвергнуто, **когда** (и если) произойдет ошибка. А получить данные из обещания можно, например, вот так:

```
GetCover().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    // Произошла ошибка.
    console.error(err);
});
```

А можно и вот так:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(await GetCover());
    } catch (err) {
        // Произошла ошибка
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```